# Random Subclass Generator: should it be used as a singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton

I am creating RandomSubclassGenerator which has members like subclass1Probability, subclass2Probability itd. Should it be used as a singleton? I dont need more than one instance of this class, but I read that "Singletons are Pathological Liars"

Comment: The question I would ask is does it *need* to be a *singleton*? What harm would be done of there were more than one instance created? Or the occasional temporary instance? For example I might use a *singleton* for a class that stores *cached data* so everything must go through the same instance.

Comment: Ok, thanks. There wouldn't be any harm, I think.